# mysqli - how to get exact ($i) raw field from query

Tags: php, mysqli

Need to receive data of fields from $i raw of mysqli object.

```
$res = $mysqli->query("SELECT mood,count(mood) as number FROM em_mood GROUP by mood ORDER by mood ASC");
$obj = $res->fetch_object();

for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++){
    if ($i==$obj->mood[$i]) $mood_result .= "<div class='chart'>".$obj->mood[$i].$obj->number[$i]."</div>";
    else $mood_result .= "<div class='chart'>empty</div>";
}
```

Explanation:
$obj->mood is equal from 1 to 10.
if $obj->mood is missing "2" for example, I need to exchange it with empty div.
In other words, what is the syntax of getting field [mood] value in lets say second raw? something like $obj[2][mood]?

### **Update:**

Looks like it works like this:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++){
    $res = $mysqli->query("SELECT mood,count(mood) as number FROM em_mood WHERE date>=CURDATE()-INTERVAL 30 DAY and mood=".$i);
    $obj = $res->fetch_object();
    echo $obj->mood." - ".$obj->number."<br>";
}
```

Is there any way to make this more simple? To don`t make 10 mysqli queries?

Comment: what is "exact raw field"?

Comment: It isn't clear what you are asking for. What value do you want, and how does it differ from the result you are currently getting?

Comment: I see that you are calling `fetch_object()` outside of the loop. If multiple rows are expected, you should be calling it inside a `while` loop [as in the many documented examples](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-object.php)

Comment: FYI: `$obj->mood` isn't an array, it's a string.  What are you trying to do?  How many rows does your query return?  Usually you use `fetch_object()` like this to get each row: `while ($obj = $result->fetch_object()){}`.

Comment: so what is the syntax of getting field [mood] value in lets say second raw? something like $obj[2][mood]

Comment: Do you mean *row*, which would be the second iteration of the `for` loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$raw = [];
$sql = "SELECT mood,count(mood) as number FROM em_mood GROUP by mood";
$res = $mysqli->query($sql);
while ($obj = $res->fetch_object())
{
    $raw[$obj->mood] = $obj->number;
}
```

now you will have your "raw" data all right

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++){
    if (isset($raw[$i])) {
        $mood_result .= "<div class='chart'>$i - $raw[$i]</div>";
    } else {
        $mood_result .= "<div class='chart'>empty</div>";
    }
}
```